# Why do we have to add comma ',' in args in python multithreading?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I am new to python and I am not sure why we use Comma ',' in args for Thread
Eg:

```
import threading
import time

semaphore = threading.BoundedSemaphore(value=5)

def access(thread_number):
    print("{}: Trying access...".format(thread_number))

    semaphore.acquire()

    print("{}: Access granted!".format(thread_number))

    print("{}: waiting 5 seconds...".format(thread_number))

    time.sleep(5)
    semaphore.release()

    print("{}: Releasing!...".format(thread_number))


for thread_number in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=access, args=(thread_number,))
    t.start()
```

Why is it valid?
how does "args = (thread_number,)" need comma at the end?

Comment: The comma is what defines the tuple that `args` expects.

Comment: So does that require even if we just have one variable?

Comment: Yes, because `(x)` isn't a tuple, while `(x,)` is. Except for the empty tuple `()`, a tuple is *always* defined by a comma, not by parentheses. The parentheses are only necessary here to disambiguate the tuple-comma from the fiction-argument-list commas.

Comment: Okay, that clears the reason for comma, Thank you!! @chepner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alas, this isn't especially easy - it's at the intersection of some dark corners of Python's syntax.

First, the comma is needed to make a tuple, with a single element, containing the thread number:

```
>>> 6
6
>>> 6,
(6,)
>>> (6,)
(6,)
>>> (6)
6
```

See? Without a comma, or with *just* parentheses, 6 is just the int 6. But with a comma - and with or without parentheses - it becomes a tuple containing the int 6 as its only element.

Why does it need to be a tuple? You're soon going to be told that it actually doesn't ;-) , but before then consider that you *may* need to pass any number of arguments to a thread. So the expression after `args=` must yield a sequence.

But if the appearance of comma makes a tuple, why do you also need parentheses? That's an "intersection of some dark corners": a comma in an argument list *also* seperates arguments, and that takes precedence in this context. So the parentheses are needed to enforce the intent: "this comma doesn't mean the next argument is starting - this comma means I want a tuple".

To avoid having to think about all that, you can use a list as a sequence instead in this context:

```
    t = threading.Thread(target=access, args=[thread_number])
```

The implementation of `Thread` couldn't care less which kind of sequence is passed as the value of `args=`, and lots of code actually uses a list instead of a tuple. However, last time I looked, that had not been documented, so it's a bit risky.

### EDIT

I since [added a request to the Python issue tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue45735) requesting that we finally document that a list is fine in this context. It always has been. Looks all but certain that this documentation change will be made.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining this! This cleared like all the questions.

Comment: Glad it helped! For encouragement, I'll say a strong case can be made for that Python's syntax for a 1-element tuple is likely the ugliest (surprising, ..., _weird_) syntax in the language. So don't fear bumping into something new "like this" every day ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you add comma then for python it's a tuple and empty parentheses is also tuple

```
>>> type( (1,) )
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type( (1) )
<class 'int'>
>>> type( (1,2))
<class 'tuple'>
>>> type( () )
<class 'tuple'>
```